# How do I insert a whole div element and forms into the page using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a login form on top of the header. But when user is logged in, I want the form to disappear. I will check if user is not logged in, if so then I should add the form. But I want to do it in the javascript.

Comment: It would be easier to hide/show the HTML based on the logged in state of the user

Comment: hide header-content: `document.getElementById('header-content').style.display = 'none';`. To show `document.getElementById('header-content').style.display = 'block';` or you can use `inline`.

Comment: but im using .load() method for my header and footer to be included in my other pages

Comment: Should we do your home work?? please provide some codes

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer to what you're asking is to use jQuery's `append()` function.

The problem with this is that you will need to insert it all as text, which is going to become a maintenance problem. Definitely.

The better way is to insert the div and hide it by default using `display:none` and to programmatically set it to `display:block` when needed.

If you use something like Angular, you could also include the div by inserting the template when needed. But the use of `display` for this purpose is very widely accepted as the right way.

**Edit:**

Since you're using `load()` already for some parts of the page, you could probably do the same here.

Add a container tag to the HTML:

```
<div id="loginContainer"></div>
```

Add the nested content like this:

```
$("#loginContainer").load("http://some.url.com/path");
```

Hide it again with `html()`

```
$("#loginContainer").html("");
```

Comment: the thing is im using .load method to include my headers and footer across my other pages,

Comment: I tried .addClass/.removeClass but it doest seem to update across the other pages. Will append() work?

Comment: These do different things. `append()` adds content to a tag, which is why I suggest that as a way to insert your template into the page. `addClass()` and `removeClass()` change which CSS classes are associated with a tag. To modify a specific element of the style directly (like I suggest with 'display'), you would use jQuery's `css()` function. So `$("loginSelector").css("display", "none")` will hide the login form.

Comment: will this update throughout the other pages when I include the script to each and every html page?

Comment: This is another reason why embedding the template and setting its `display` to `none` is the preferred way. It will be there on each page, but hidden. Only show it when needed.

Comment: About the `load()` strategy: The `loginContainer` div is empty on all pages unless you embed it. Which is what I thought you wanted.

Comment: oh ok, ill try the css() method , because the .addClass/removeClass doest update throughout.

Comment: If you have multiple pages including the same header, then none of these methods will update them all (because they are unrelated). You either need to execute the script to hide or show on each page, or change your architecture to have a main page containing header, footer and sidebar, with nested content that is loaded dynamically. This way, the header becomes global state. Angular would be my pick to enable this. In your case, just execute the script when each page loads to preferentially show or hide the login container.